# Sound Indicator integration help

Tags: unity, sound, python, indicator

I have been trying to add my application to the Sound Indicator menu in Unity for about a week now. The lack of documentation on the subject is honestly appalling. Any links I can find which claim to be documentation are dead.

Here's where I am: I used the mopidy-mpris source as a guide for how to build a DBus service that complies with the MPRIS specification. I can run this service, and communicate with/control it using a nifty Python MPRIS client (https://github.com/airtower-luna/mpris-python). I am able to query all properties with `qdbus` and everything appears to be working to spec as far as MPRIS goes.

I had read in a few posts that to add an application to the Sound Indicator, that you should add it to the `/com/canonical/indicator/sound/interested-media-players` key within dconf (it also needed a `.desktop` file in `~/.local/share/applications`). I did this, and my application showed up in the Sound Indicator upon logging in/out. This looked great, but when I clicked on my Application, it simply started swirling over the play button. My application does start, but I cannot interact with it via the menu. I used `dbus-monitor` to look at dbus messages being sent/received and I got nothing. I sent some manual ones using the above MPRIS client, and I could see them in dbus-monitor and they successfully controlled the player, so at least that was working.

I looked through the mopidy source some more and found that they mention sending a launch notification to the sound indicator by creating an Indicator service. Of course, they used an old indicate module, but I used `gi.repository.Indicate` instead, and it basically fell into place. I initialize an indicate server like so:

```
from gi.repository import Indicate
indicate_server = Indicate.Server()
indicate_server.set_type('music.myapp')
indicate_server.set_desktop_file(os.path.abspath('myapp.desktop'))
indicate_server.show()
```

This did nothing. I still get a stuck/spinning/loading animation on the play button and have no control.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Best case: a link to the actual documentation would be great.

Comment: May be its looking for non-implemented method or properties. Have you implemented all these methods listed here https://specifications.freedesktop.org/mpris-spec/latest/Player_Interface.html  and more specifically the `Can..`  properties. If you are developing an open source project could you share some code or post link for github project?